# Looking up polygons in a shapefile that point belong in... why does it work with some shapefiles, not with others?

Tags: r, gis, shapefile

I am trying to look up census tract info by lat/lon coordinates using the census.gov shapefile located [here](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/TRACT/tl_2015_27_tract.zip):

This has been working quite successfully with code proposed by @lukeA for the ZCTA shapefile. See the original question and resolution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703219/from-a-shapefile-with-polygons-areas-and-points-lat-lon-figure-out-which-pol/33703800#33703800):

However, when I changed the shapefile to census tract, suddenly the lookup functionality broke, and I can't seem to figure out why. The [documentation](http://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/maps-data/data/tiger/tgrshp2015/TGRSHP2015_TechDoc_Ch2.pdf) on the shapefile indicates that it is using NAD83 projection, which is the same as the ZCTA shapefile. The code doesn't return any errors, per se... but the output is all `NA`.

Here is the code:

```
library(maptools)
library(maps)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

mn.zip.map <- readShapePoly("tl_2015_27_tract.shp")
proj4string(mn.zip.map) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=15 +datum=NAD83")
mn.zip.map <- spTransform(mn.zip.map, CRS("+proj=longlat"))
latlong <- data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=1))
latlong$lat <- c(44.730178, 44.784711, 44.943008)
latlong$long <- c(-93.235381, -93.476415, -93.303201)
coordinates(latlong) = ~long+lat
proj4string(latlong) <- CRS(proj4string(mn.zip.map))
over(latlong, mn.zip.map)
```

With output:

```
STATEFP COUNTYFP TRACTCE GEOID NAME NAMELSAD MTFCC FUNCSTAT ALAND AWATER INTPTLAT INTPTLON
1    <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA> <NA>     <NA>  <NA>     <NA>    NA     NA     <NA>     <NA>
2    <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA> <NA>     <NA>  <NA>     <NA>    NA     NA     <NA>     <NA>
3    <NA>     <NA>    <NA>  <NA> <NA>     <NA>  <NA>     <NA>    NA     NA     <NA>     <NA>
```

Again, clearly I am missing some nuance of GIS and geocoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing something wrong with the projections. Use `rgdal::readOGR()` instead of `maptools::readShapePoly()`, this handles the projection information automatically:

```
library("rgdal")
mn.zip.map <- readOGR(".", "tl_2015_27_tract")
proj4string(mn.zip.map)
# [1] "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
latlong <- data.frame(lat=c(44.730178, 44.784711, 44.943008),
                      long=c(-93.235381, -93.476415, -93.303201))
coordinates(latlong) <- ~long+lat
proj4string(latlong) <- CRS(proj4string(mn.zip.map))
over(latlong, mn.zip.map)
#   STATEFP COUNTYFP TRACTCE       GEOID   NAME            NAMELSAD MTFCC
# 1      27      037  060812 27037060812 608.12 Census Tract 608.12 G5020
# 2      27      139  080301 27139080301 803.01 Census Tract 803.01 G5020
# 3      27      053  108000 27053108000   1080   Census Tract 1080 G5020
#   FUNCSTAT    ALAND  AWATER    INTPTLAT     INTPTLON
# 1        S  3654009  299711 +44.7246681 -093.2316029
# 2        S 29771331 2237086 +44.7886836 -093.4454977
# 3        S   678381       0 +44.9444245 -093.3014752

plot(mn.zip.map, axes=TRUE)
plot(latlong, add=TRUE, col="red")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks! That works great. I'll definitely use readOGR() instead of readShapePoly() from now on. I'm a little curious as to what the projection problem was... but mostly just glad to have a solution. Thanks again.

Comment: `+proj=utm +zone=15` is wrong for the shapefile, you obtained coordinates somewhere around (-97.49, 0.00040); see the correct proj4string above.